# multiplying all numbers inside different <p> and then sum it up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a shoppingcart page and each product that are displayed on the shoopingcart page is inside a div box.

Each div box have a price that is displayed like this `<p id="price">599<p>`

How can I grab all the numbers inside these

and then sum it up and display the total in another `<p></p>` ?

Depending on how many products are in the shoppingcart that many div boxes are generated. Lets say we have 2 products which mean 2 div boxes:

```
<div id="holder@(model.ProductId)" class="holder">  
             <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Image)" alt="" />
               <div class="productinfo">
               <h2>Bike</h2> 
               <p>It will take 24 hours to deliver</p>    
               </div>
                <div class="productprice">     
                <p class="price">599<p>                                    
               </div>
```

second one:

```
<div id="holder@(model.ProductId)" class="holder">  
             <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Image)" alt="" />
               <div class="productinfo">
               <h2>car</h2> 
               <p>It will take 24 hours to deliver</p>    
               </div>
                <div class="productprice">     
                <p class="price">1599<p>                                     
               </div>
```

this is the button where this function should get triggered:

```
<input type="button" value="Update" class="a" />
```

How can I do this with Jquery, somehow I need to check how many `<p class="price"><p>` there is and then eval() them and then multiply them and store the total in a different`<p></p>`?

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: start with `$('p.price').each()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var total = 0;
$("p.price").each(function(i){
   total += parseFloat($(this).text(), 10);
});
```

**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/3tMfr/6/)**

Comment: i dislike parseInt and rather prefer a direct type conversion and intercept NaN.

Comment: The line should read

"total += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);"

Otherwise you'll get caught by Javascript's friendly default octal int parsing.

Comment: at least you should take `parseFloat(x,10)`

Comment: When I checked the example it was showing 
1
2
3
4
5
the <P> numbers were not multiplied?

Comment: I always forget that darn radix! Thanks for the comments. I went ahead and changed it to parseFloat as well...that's definitely a better type considering it is prices.

Comment: @AlianaRose, check the console, that's where the 'output' is being displayed. Secondly, I was under the impression that this was supposed to be added and not multiplied, but I can change that if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.a').click(function(){
   var total = 0;
   $('.price').each(function(){
    total += parseInt($(this).text());
   });

   //update total

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to Chase`s Solution:

```
var total = 0;
$("p.price").each(function(i){
    total += !isNaN(c = +$(this).text())?c:0;
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3tMfr/3/)